# sendEmail as respondent in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way for a respondent of a form to use the sendEmail method and send the email as them, instead as the creator of the form?

Comment: it may suit your purposes to use the 'replyTo' argument, which allows you to specify a Reply-To address for the sent message that can differ from the sender.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,String)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible since the GmailApp or MailApp service only allows you to send emails on behalf of addresses that are set as aliases in your Gmail account.